# Jquery- Function being skipped when run second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, web

```js
/**
 Returns a string with the iTunes data in table html format
**/
var appendValues = function(songArray) {
 songArray.each(function() { 
  var title = $(this).find("im\\:name").eq(0).text();
  var songImage = $(this).find("im\\:image").eq(0).text(); 
  var artist = $(this).find("im\\:artist").text();
  var album = $(this).find("im\\:collection").children().eq(0).text(); 
  var sample = $(this).find("link").eq(1).attr("href");
    
  $("#songs").append(
   "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + title + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + artist + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + album + "</td>" +
    "<td><img src=\"" + songImage + "\"/></td>" +
    "<td><audio controls>" +
      "<source src=\"" + sample + "\" type=\"audio/x-m4a\">" +
      "<source src=\"" + sample + "\" type=\"audio/x-m4a\">" +
    "Your browser does not support the audio element." +
    "</audio></td>" +
   "</tr>");
 });
}

/**
 Gets top song list from iTunes. Accepts two parameters, country and songNumber, which are inserted into URL.  Displays song list in HTML.
**/
var getSongs = function( country, songNumber ){
   $.get("https://itunes.apple.com/" + country + "/rss/topsongs/limit=" + songNumber + "/xml", function(data){
  var songArray = $(data).find("entry");
  appendValues(songArray); //Function that adds values to html table
  
 }, "xml");
}

/**
 Gets user input from dropdown menu and slider. Calls getSongs function to update song list.
**/
var updateSongs = function(){
 
 //Get country input
 var country = $("#dropdown").val();
 
 if (country == "united_states"){
  country = "us";
 } else if(country == "india"){
  country = "in";
 } else {
  country = "tr";
 }
 
 //Get song number input
 var songNumber = $("#slider").slider("value");
 
 //Setup HTML table
 $("#songs").append(
  "<caption>iTunes Top Hits</caption>" +
  "<tr>" + 
   "<td colspan=\"5\">" +
    "<form>" +
    "<!-- Select menu found at https://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/ -->" +
      "<label for=\"select-choice-0\" class=\"select\">Select Country: </label>" +
     "<select name=\"select-choice-0\" id=\"dropdown\">" +
       "<option value=\"united_states\">United States</option>" +
       "<option value=\"india\">India</option>" +
       "<option value=\"turkey\">Turkey</option>" +
     "</select>" +
      "<br><br>" +
     "<div id=\"songNumber\">Number of Songs: <span id=\"number\">10</span><div id=\"slider\"></div></div>" +
      "<br><br>" +
      "<input type=\"button\" id=\"update\" value=\"Update\">" +
    "</form>" +
   "</td>" +
  "</tr>" +
  "<tr>" +
   "<th>Song Title</th>" +
   "<th>Artist</th>" +
   "<th>Album</th>" +
   "<th>Album Cover</th>" +
   "<th>Song Sample</th>" +
  "</tr>"
 );
 
 setupSlider();
 
 //Refresh song list
 getSongs(country, songNumber);
}

var setupSlider = function(){
 //Sets up the slider
 $("#slider").slider({
   orientation: "horizontal",
   range: 5,
   max: 30,
   value: 10
   //slide: updateText,
   //change: updateText
 });
}

var erase = function(){
 $("#songs tr").remove();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 setupSlider();
 
 var country = "us";
 var val = $("#slider").slider("option", "value");
 getSongs(country, val);
 
 //On Update click, erase the old song list and update with current list.
 $("#update").click(function() {
  erase();
  updateSongs();
 });
});
```

```css
table {
 table-layout: fixed; 
 width: 75%;
 margin: auto;
 
}

td {
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

audio {
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
 padding: 5px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 width: 100px;
}

caption {
 font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 1.2em;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
}

tr:nth-of-type(even) {
 background-color: #eaeaea;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}

td:nth-of-type(4) {
 text-align:center;
}

td:nth-of-type(5) {
 text-align:center;
}

#slider {
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <!-- Custom Widget Theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
 <!-- jQuery Library -->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> 
 <!-- jQuery UI Library -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <!-- CSS style sheet-->
    <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Javascript-->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<table  id="songs">
 <caption>iTunes Top Hits</caption>
 <tr> 
  <td colspan="5">
   <form>
     <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Select Country: </label>
    <select name="select-choice-0" id="dropdown">
      <option value="united_states">United States</option>
      <option value="india">India</option>
      <option value="turkey">Turkey</option>
    </select>
     <br><br>
    <div id="songNumber">Number of Songs: <span id="number">10</span><div id="slider"></div></div>
     <br><br>
     <input type="button" id="update" value="Update">
   </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <th>Song Title</th>
  <th>Artist</th>
  <th>Album</th>
  <th>Album Cover</th>
  <th>Song Sample</th>
 </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a function that makes an ajax call to itunes and gets a list of songs that are appended to a html table, with an update button that runs the same function again.  I run the function when I load the page and everything loads fine, but when I click update, the function is skipped. I can watch it in firefox debugger go right past it. EDIT: I've added a code snippet, but it doesnt display properly; however, the problem remains.

Comment: When dynamically loaded data, `#update` click event is fired?

Comment: please provide jsfiddle for that code.

Comment: can you show your appendValues() method?

Comment: I've added the full code.

Comment: You are removing the original `#update` button which is the one that has been bound to the (click) event handler.  When you re-add the button, it does not have the event handler bound to it anymore, since it is a new DOM element you are adding. Try moving the button on top of the table... Or event delegation (as answered by @madalin below)

Answer (score 2):

Try event delegation:

```
$("body").on('click','#update',function() {
        erase();
        updateSongs();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `erase()` method is removing the full DOM element (not it's content). Probably the `appendValues` method requires that  tag to work

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the .slice method to choose to only erase what came after the first two rows.  This fixed the problem that Ochi raised above, with removing the original #update button with the events tied to it.